# perfect forwarding through base class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, perfect-forwarding

I want to be able to perfect forward argument to derived class through base class. The only idea I have is to implement not virtual perfect forwarding function in base class and have virtual functions overloads for `lvalues` and `rvalues`. Something like this:

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class base_t
{
public:
    virtual ~base_t() = default;

    template<typename T>
    void perfect_forward(T&& value)
    {
        process(std::forward<T>(value));
    }

protected:
    virtual void process(const std::string& value) = 0;
    virtual void process(std::string&& value) = 0;
};

class derived_t : public base_t
{
protected:
    void process(const std::string& value) override final
    {
        std::cout << "derived_t::process(const lvalue&)" << std::endl;
    }

    void process(std::string&& value) override final
    {
        std::cout << "derived_t::process(rvalue&&)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const std::string lvalue;
    auto rvalue = []() { return std::string(); };

    std::unique_ptr<base_t> base(new derived_t);
    base->perfect_forward(lvalue);
    base->perfect_forward(rvalue());
}
```

But this has a little meaning, because instead of template `perfect_forward` function in base class I can simply provide two overload for virtual `process`. How I can avoid code duplicate in derived class for `process` method and use `std::forward` there through base_t interface?

Comment: If you want dynamic polymorphism you'll need the virtual call at some point and function templates cannot be virtual of course. You can have a templated function in `derived_t` which can be called from both overloads in the derived class.

Comment: It seems that providing two overloads for virtual function in base class is the simplest way :(

Comment: You can just use `virtual void process(std::string value)`.

Comment: Simple, yes, but as Effective Modern C++ learns us in item 41, this is not always a best choice.

Comment: Does "not always a best choice" mean "never"? You seem to have discarded the suggestion without any thought.

Comment: Simple, my desire to use perfect forwarding is to minimize copy ctors. I have profiled heap for my application and found that most part of memory pressure is coming from std::string copying operations. In my case passing by value will cost two move ctors. And I want to eliminate any possible overhead entirely.

Comment: Do you really want to do different thing for the both overloads ? Do you store the `std::string` ?

Comment: Jarod42, yes the typical step in real process is to store std::string inside std::unordered_map.

Comment: A string move is significantly cheaper than a string copy. You're paying 1 extra move operation in the worst case for reducing the code you have to write by about 50%.

Comment: A string move isn't necessarily cheaper than a string copy if SSO is in effect.

Comment: Only provide rvalue overload. user has to be explicit for the copy.

Comment: Simple, you are absolutely right. But I'm asking if it is possible via usage of perfect forward to eliminate this one extra move ctor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to take the `std::string` by value, there is an approach using a mixin class, but it requires changing your class hierachy:

```
template<class D>
class process_mixin : public base_t {
protected:
    void process(std::string const& value) override final {
        return ((D*)this)->do_process(value);
    }

    void process(std::string&& value) override final {
        return ((D*)this)->do_process(std::move(value));
    }
};

class derived_t : public process_mixin<derived_t> {
protected:
    template<typename T>
    void do_process(T&& value) {
    }

    friend process_mixin<derived_t>;
};
```

`process_mixin` only has to be written once. From then on anything that derives from `base_t` can instead derive from `process_mixin` and you get a perfect forwarding interface.